# Will Rand(x) always generate the same number for the same value of x on any SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

It seems that `Select Rand(5)` always returns the same number - I checked on three computers. But can I assume that it will always (on any SQL Server instance) return the same number (0.713666525097956)?

And of course, if that will be the case for any other parameter of `Rand()` function.

Comment: There's no guarantee that this value will be constant across different sql server versions. What is the actual question? You probably have a reason for asking this

Comment: Yes, I would like to know if the code will always execute in the same manner. On the other hand, I need some pseudorandomness. This is related to some statistical considerations.

Comment: `rand` is kind of niche; case in point: `select rand() from sys.all_objects`.And given the same seed, yes. It will always return the exact same value, on any instance.  If you need non-cryptographically secure randomness, I'd recommend doing something like `abs(checksum(newid()))`. As it's based of a basically random guid, you'll get a new random number every time it's called. If you need cryptographically secure randomness, look at [crypt_gen_random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/crypt-gen-random-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and expected behaviour:

> Returns a **pseudo-random** `float` value from 0 through 1, exclusive.
>
> ##### *seed*
>
> Is an integer [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (`tinyint`, `smallint`, or `int`) that gives the seed value. If *seed* isn't specified, the SQL Server Database Engine assigns a seed value at random. **For a specified seed value, the result returned is always the same.**

Emphasis mine.

If you want a *true* random number `RAND` is not your friend.

Comment: While you can't have a **TRUE** random number, using something like `SELECT RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(64))) FROM sys.sysobjects` gets you close.